# Tomcat container allow access to host

Tags: java, maven, docker, tomcat

I have a Tomcat container running on my remote server. Originally, I allowed all ip addresses in the context.xml file in manager. I was able to deploy war remotely with the maven tomcat 7 plugin. However, I realise that it is very insecure as anyone can deploy the war if they know the username and password. Now, I plan to SSH to my server, pull the project from github and then execute the maven goals and deploy to the tomcat container. The only problem is I keep getting this access denied error. I have tried putting the public ip of my server and 0.0.0.0 in the allow field of Valve. I want manager webapp to only allow access from the host.

Comment: `127.0.0.1` or better `localhost` is the name of "the same" host. Typically `localhost` is defined as the IPV6 address of *the same* computer these days - use that one or both. Or just deploy through file access to the webapps directory, no need for the manager application.

Comment: In a Docker context, a service that listens on 127.0.0.1 is unreachable outside the container.  Also in a Docker context, `localhost` means the same _container_, not necessarily the host.

Comment: Can you build a custom image that has Tomcat and your application installed?

Comment: I realise that it is pointless to deploy from the host to the container through maven when I can just docker copy to the container. Anyway, I now realise that 127.0.0.1/localhost within a container means the container itself.